# Kotlin spring controller integration test not working

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-security, integration-testing

struggling here, I have been stuck on this for about a week now, don't know how to get this working. I am trying to write a integration test to check if my introduced spring variable validation in my controller is working, but I am running into issues on how to exactly do this in kotlin.

With where I am now, I have all the dependencies autowired, and can pass the @AuthenticationPrincipal layer of my controller and the code executes, but if I debug, the userService which is being used for user retrieval, and has been autowired is null in the controller(not NPE but just null when debugging inside of the controller). It seems there is an issue with wiring in that service/dependency?

I have also tried the mvc.StandAloneSetup(UserController) and have gotten that to work with all the dependencies, but unfourtunately I had to abandon that approach, because I could not figure out how pass the @AuthenticationPrincipal.. @WithUSerDetails, @WithMockUser, @WithUser, none of which worked. Any advice onw hat I am doing wrong? New to kotlin so don't know much

Additionally I had some success with mappings that did not require authenticaiton, but the validation seemed to always spout random errors(error from previous test execution) issue with context clearing?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
open class UsersControllerTest {

@Autowired lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc
@Autowired lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

@Autowired private var db = testDatabase()
@Autowired private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
@Autowired private lateinit var dependency : dependency
@Autowired private lateinit var usersService : UsersService
@Autowired private lateinit var someUserService : someUserService

@Autowired private lateinit var userController: UsersController
@MockBean  private lateinit var userPrincipal: UserPrincipal
@Autowired private lateinit var context: WebApplicationContext


@BeforeEach
fun init(){
    dependency = Dependency()
    userRepository = UserRepository(db)
    userRepository.insert(validUser)
    usersService = UsersService(userRepository,dependency,"var")
    someUserService = SomeUserService(usersService)
    userController = UsersController(usersService,someUserService,dependency)
    userPrincipal = UserPrincipal(validUser, null)
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build()
}
@AfterEach
open fun cleanup() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
}

@Test
@WithUserDetails("admin",serviceBeanName = "userService", setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_EXECUTION)

fun getUsers() {
    val result = mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users/",{false}).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        )
    ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
        .andReturn()
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@CrossOrigin(origins = ["*"])
@RequestMapping("${API_ROOT}users/")
open class UsersController @Autowired constructor(
    private val usersService: UsersService,
    private val someService: SomeService,
    private val dependency: dependency,
) {
    companion object {
        fun validatePermissions(principal: UserPrincipal, userId: UserId) {
            if (principal.user.id != userId && 
            ...
        }

 
@GetMapping
@RolesAllowed(ROLE_ADMIN)
fun getAllUsers(
    @AuthenticationPrincipal principal: UserPrincipal,
    @RequestParam(value = "admin", required = false) includeAdmin: Boolean = false,
    @RequestParam(value = "guest", required = false) includeGuest: Boolean = false,
): List<User> {
    validatePermissions()
    return usersService.getAll()
}
```

Comment: I noticed you are using the profile `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. Is there a `UsersService` defined in the test profile? If not, that is likely why it is null in the Controller.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, did not think of this. But sadly, this is not the cause of the issue, just tried all the available profiles, the UsersService is still null in the controller. Actually, everything is null in the controller, UsersService, SomeService and the dependency, maybe this is an issue with @Autowired or  Gradle dependencies?

Comment: You are also @Autowiring MockMvc and later overriding that value `this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build()`. Try removing the entire `init` method.

Comment: Tried removing it, still everything is null inside of the UserController -> UsersService, SomeService and the dependency,

Comment: ANy more ideas? Still stuck....